# What happens during DDoS attack on distributed system?

Tags: security, distributed-computing, ddos, denial-of-service

In case of a centralized system, DDoS attacks are just on a particular IP. What happens when you do a DDoS attack on a distributed system like Facebook or Google or any other company that has a pool of IP address?
How does that proceed and is dealt with?

Comment: "In case of a centralized system, DDoS attacks are just on a particular IP." --> Where did you find this ?

Comment: It's quite intuitive tbh. If you use your own server, it has a fixed IP and if I want to dos attack, all I'll need to do is bombard your particular IP address.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, i understood it in the other way